# What to do after the web application is developed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deployment

I am a newbie to IT Field.

I have just finished a small web application using `mvc` in `C#.net (Visual Studio 2012)`

And I have used `SQL Server Management studio 2008` to create database.

Now I want my site to be hosted on Server.

So, my questions are :

```
 1) Should I copy my database(.mdf and .ldf) files to App_Data? If yes then how?

 2) After the database issue is cleared how to deploy the web application and 
    put it on the server?
```

Can anyone suggest me a simple nice tutorial? Or can you give me just basic understanding?

Comment: do you have your own server or you want to rent server from any hosting provider?

Comment: @kandroid No, I don't have my own server and neither I want to rent server from any hosting provider. `somee.com` gives me 150 MB of storage for free and that's more than enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is

1. Create a database in somee.com and deploy your database over there. You can access your database in somee.com from management studio
2. Get your ftp access from somee.com and publish your project over there from visual studio.

thats it..

Answer (score 1):

Consider this thread http://forums.asp.net/t/1903127.aspx
there are lots of article written on how to accomplish this on codeproject